# View doesn't display but Controller works fine when I enter in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am starting to study and put into practice asp.net MVC, I have a home controller and index action method and have deployed the project in local IIS. It works fine when I just enter the alias or projectname and controller, please see image below
[image]

But, when I include the view (.cshtml) in the Url or address bar it doesn't work as expected,

[image]

Why is it working properly if I did not include the .cshtml in the url? thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you can't request a cshtml file.

Comment: So it works as it is supposed to. Why do you need the file extension in the url?

Comment: *ASP.NET MVC maps the URL to a method call on a controller, rather than some physical file*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, the request is handled by the controller. That's why you can't access the file directly.

For a basic explanation why and how, you can check it out [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing).

Answer (score 2):

**Routing** is the one of the good mechanism in MVC.
It will map your url request to subsequent Controller and it's action and then render html to browser.

The html page would be cshtml, aspx or custom if you want.

Go through : http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc

Hope it will help you.